# Как в yandex mapkit 3.1.2 получить TrafficLayer

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

В версии 3.0 можно получить так:

```
trafficLayer = mapView.getMap().getTrafficLayer();
```

а в новой [такого метода нет](https://tech.yandex.com/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/android/mapkit/ref/com/yandex/mapkit/traffic/TrafficLayer-docpage/)

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.

```
trafficLayer = MapKitFactory.getInstance().createTrafficLayer(mapview.getMapWindow());
```